# Check if IPV4 and IPV6 address might be the same

Tags: ip-address, ipv6, multicast, ipv4

Imagine I have 2 IP addresses, one in IPV4 format and the other in IPV6 format.

Is there a way to check if they are possibly the same address?

The comparison function would return:

- True: in case they have a good chance of being the same. Note that I left what "good chance" means open here
- False: they are definitely not the same

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

No

## Long answer

IPv4 and IPv6 adresses aren't different ways to display the same information, their whole underlying structure differs. An IPv6 adress consists of 128 Bits while an IPv4 adress only includes 32 Bits. Therefore, they can't ever be equal.

What you *can* do however is find out which MAC-adress belongs to both adresses and compare those. This gives you an idea about the device behind those adresses. ***At least as long as there is no MAC address randomization involved.***

Answer (score 2):

They can never be the same address because IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, while IPv6 addresses are 128-bit unsigned integers. IPv4 and IPv6 are two separate, incompatible protocols. It is like TCP port 12345 is *not* UDP port 12345; just because they share a number range does not mean they are the same ports.

Having said that, there is an IPv6 address range (`::ffff:0:0/96`) that is reserved to allow the display of IPv4 addresses in the IPv6 format. For example, `::ffff:10.11.12.13` or the equivalent `::ffff:a0b:c0d`. Those are actually IPv4 addresses, not IPv6 addresses, and they cannot be used in packets sent or received, That IPv6 address range is set aside so that a common address store, e.g. database, can store both address types in a common format.

A dual-stacked interface with an IPv4 address could have any IPv6 address, and you cannot simply look at the addresses and relate them any more than you could relate them to an IPX, AppleTalk, etc. address because they are completely different protocols.